# How to disable two input fields that are above a checkbox when clicked?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have two input boxes as in below. And, I  also have a checkbox as below.

```
<input type="text"  name="vin" id="vin" value="">

<input type="text" name="registration_number" id="registration_number" value="">

<input type="checkbox" id="car-no-rego" name="car-no-rego" >
```

If the checkbox is checked, then I want the input boxes to get disabled).

```
$('.car-no-rego:checkbox').change(function () {
    $(#vin).attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    $(#registration_number).attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

I tried liked above. But I can still type in the input fields.. Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#car-no-rego').on('change',  function () {
    $('#vin, #registration_number').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MuLeN/) <- did work

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. Try to pass the `id-selector` as a string.

Try,

```
$('#car-no-rego').change(function () {
    $('#vin').add($('#registration_number')).prop('disabled', this.checked);
})​;
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MuLeN/2/)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, `.prop()` is preferred method when it comes to set `disabled` property

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#car-no-rego').change(function () {
    $('#vin').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    $('#registration_number').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

But if you have multiple checkboxes and want to disable related input boxes then you must use class or id related to checkbox class or id.

See  below example, here two input box has ids ends with checkbox id

```
<input type="text"  name="vin" id="vin_car-no-rego1" value="">

<input type="text" name="registration_number_car-no-rego1" id="registration_number" value="">

<input type="checkbox" id="car-no-rego1" name="car-no-rego" >
```

then jQuery will be like this

```
$('input[id^="car-no-rego"]').change(function () {
    var indexValue = $(this).attr('id').replace('car-no-rego','');
    $('#vin'+indexValue+', #registration_number'+indexValue).attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```